# After Jakarta migration, GAE app throws "Request failed: Unexpected Error: java.io.IOException: written 54 > 0 content-length" until I clear cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, session-cookies, jakarta-migration

I have migrated my google app engine application from java ee 8 to jakarta 10. I used to manage sessions using `<sessions-enabled>true<sessions-enabled>` tag. But then ever since I migrated my application to jakarta 10 and started using the java 21 runtime, app-engine apis do not work. Of which behind the scenes I need app engine apis to be able to use `<sessions-enabled>`. So instead of storing my session attributes using the standard way

```
session.setAttribute(USERNAME, username);
```

I started using http cookies to store my attributes. this was the only change I made with regard to session management. So if I deploy for the first instance. I can log in and my application works well even after I log out. But if I deploy new changes , my application fails to start up , until I clear browser cache. Is there any way I can solve this. This is the error I get

```
Request failed: Unexpected Error: java.io.IOException: written 54 > 0 content-length
```

Comment: Please check this documentation on [upgrading an existing application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/upgrade-java-runtime) as servlet version should be set to `6.0`, rename your application servlets and dependencies to `jakarta.servlet.*`, update your remaining namespace to `Jakarta`.